# Invalid qualifier with Sub

Tags: excel, vba

**Do not comment, I found my issue cus I am a dumbass** (I'll leave this thread 
 for people to learn from my mistake)

(For the record I just created an account for this issue)
So I made a script that takes a cell value and searches the first 3 characters through a table and compares it with what you have inputted. If the cell corresponds with your search it will replace the value of another cell with the last three characters of the table it was searching through.

So my issue is that the compiler says that the sub is an invalid qualifier. Where there is the three asterisks is the problem.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub Search_Click()

Scan

End Sub
***Sub Scan()

    Dim Seat As Range
    Set Seat = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
    Dim returnSeat As Range
    Set returnSeat = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2")

    For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:V18")
        Dim cShorted As String
        cShorted = Left(c, 3)
        If cShorted.Value = Seat.Value Then
            returnSeat.Value = Right(c, 3)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Also, it kept highlighting "cShorted" in the "If cShorted.Value = Seat.Value Then" line

Comment: I would recommend deleting it.

Comment: You did not declare `c` variable. It must be a `Range`. `Dim c as Range'. So, you have to refer of its `.Value`. Everything referring to `c` is good to be modified as following:  `cShorted = Left(c.Value, 3)`. But not this is the error problem. The error appears because `cShorted` is a `String`. It does not have any properties/methods. So you must use `If cShorted = Seat.Value Then'. `cShorted.Value` makes VBA crazy... Besides all that are you sure that you want to achieve what the code would do? For each `c.Value` respecting condition THE SAME ranges in Sheet2 will take the `c.value`.

Comment: @Robigan 06: The code will make sens only if you know that a single range must fulfill the condition. And in such a case it would also be good to e exit the loop. Using `Exit For`.